# Large Table Optimization In SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a reporting table that is populated from various fact tables in my Data Warehouse.  The issue is that for one customer in that reporting table, it takes 46 seconds to pull his data.  The one customer has 4232424 records.  In total, the table has 5336393 records in it, and has 4 columns.  I'll post the table structure and the query I'm running.  I need to get the result time on this down to as low as possible. I've tried In Memory Tables, various Indexes, and Indexed Views.

**TABLE STRUCTURE**

```
CREATE TABLE cache.Tree
(
CustomerID    INT   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
RelationA_ID    INT   NOT NULL,
RelationB_ID    INT   NOT NULL,
NestedLevel    INT   NOT NULL,
lft      INT   NOT NULL,
rgt      INT   NOT NULL
INDEX IX_LEGS CLUSTERED (lft, rgt),
INDEX IX_LFT NONCLUSTERED (lft)
)
```

**The Report Query**

```
SELECT
tp.CustomerID AS DLine,
t.CustomerID,
t.RelationA_ID,
Level = t.NestedLevel - tp.NestedLevel,
IndentedSort = t.lft
FROM cache.UnilevelTreeWithLC2 tp
  INNER JOIN cache.UniLevelTreeWithLC2 t
   ON t.lft between tp.lft AND tp.rgt
   WHERE tp.CustomerID = 7664
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE 1: Query Execution Plan**
[image: Query Execution Plan]

**UPDATE 2:  Solved**
I was able to get permission to filter out inactive people in the tree. This has cut the query execution in almost half, if I keep the indexes I put on the table.

Comment: Please post the query plan.   I suspect INDEX IX_LFT NONCLUSTERED (lft) is not being used.  But the with the other two indexes should cover the join and where.   And you have defraged the indexes?

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan yet and statistics? I recommend using these statistics: `SET STATISTICS IO ON`
`SET STATISTICS TIME ON` , just remember to turn them off. Please use these tools to compare your queries and index changes, then post your questions along with the results.

Comment: I doubt any indexing is going to help here to be honest. You are return 4.2 million of 5.3 million rows. That is 80% of the total rows in the table. The bigger question is why do you have a report that is displaying 4.2 million rows?

Comment: @Frisbee : Plan Posted

Comment: @SeanLange :  This is a report for a client.  Each customer has a nested tree, and they need to see their entire tree.

Comment: Well 46 seconds for a report with 4.2 million rows sounds pretty damn fast to me. I can't imagine a human being able to parse that much data.

Comment: You have two seeks - I don't think it is going to get better.  You have a nested loop - you could try forcing another type of join but I don't think that would help.   Like I said INDEX IX_LFT is not used.

Comment: That plan doesn't match your query.

Answer (score 1):

Try `forcescan` - for a query that pulls 80% of a narrow table I would expect SQL to scan but it might not because of bad stats or one of the various cardinality estimation bugs (that are fixed but require traceflags to enable).

I would also ditch the celko-sets - a single parent_id col will make your table even narrower, which should speed up these throughput bound cases, spare you the left/right maintenance, and be very fast with recursive queries.